# Toggling touch sensitivity for WACOM CTH-300 Bamboo Pad

Tags: touchpad, 14.10, wacom, bamboo

Under Ubuntu 14.10, I am having trouble configuring a wireless **WACOM CTH-300 Bamboo Pad** to toggle touch sensitivity on and off. At this point, the pen and tablet work as expected (mouse movement, pressure sensitivity, etc), and touch sensitivity is enabled as well (both single and multi-finger gestures work as expected).

However, upon running `xsetwacom --list devices` in a terminal, the following is returned:

```
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, wireless stylus  id: 12  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, wireless eraser  id: 16  type: ERASER    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Bamboo Pad, wireless pad id: 17  type: PAD
```

...and nothing is stated about a `TOUCH` device. All of the previous answers I have stumbled upon suggest some sequence of `xsetwacom` commands to turn the `TOUCH` option off, but I do not know where to begin when that option isn't even listed.

I am worried that my extensive hacking and package-installing to get the product fully functional in the first place is the cause of this current weird behavior. The WACOM tab in System Settings still states that no tablet is detected.

Is there any reliable way to toggle touch sensitivity on and off for this product? I plan to have the functionality turned on and off frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
xsetwacom --set "device name" Gesture off        # disable multitouch gestures or

xsetwacom --set "device name" Touch off          # disable touch
```